# Docker-compose starts a single container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose and I'm trying to run an express app and postgres db in docker containers.
My problem is that it only starts postgres image, but express app is not running.

What am I doing wrong?

I've published it on my github: https://github.com/ayakymyshyn/docker-playground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at your [docker-compose file](https://github.com/ayakymyshyn/docker-playground/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ayakymyshyn/docker-playground/blob/master/Dockerfile), i assume that your intention is that the [`web`](https://github.com/ayakymyshyn/docker-playground/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L3) service in the compose will actually run the image produced by the Dockerfile.

if that is the case, you need to modify the compose file and tell it to [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) an image based on the Dockerfile.

it should look something like

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services: 
  web: 
    image: node
    build: .  # <--- this is the missing line
    depends_on: 
      - db
    ports: 
      - '3001:3001'
  db: 
    image: postgres
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123123123
      POSTGRES_USER: yakym
      POSTGRES_DB: jwt
    volumes: 
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports: 
      - '5433:5433'
```

Comment: That's not worked for me :( But your comment forced me to try build my own image first and than use it like: `image: my-image-name`, and it worked!